# How do I pass an empty array as a default function parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how default parameters work in Javascript. From my knowledge so far, it should be fairly straightforward - if I have a function like so:

```
function calculateTotal(prices = [], tip = 0, tax = 0) {
    return prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + tip + tax
}
```

running

```
console.log(calculateTotal(tip = 4))
```

should print out `4`, but it prints out `Uncaught TypeError: prices.reduce is not a function` and `NaN`, because apparently `prices` is initialized to `undefined` as opposed to the default value of `[]`. However, if I do

```
console.log(calculateTotal([], tip = 4))
```

it prints `4`. Is there something I'm missing about using arrays as default parameters?

Comment: `console.log(calculateTotal(tip = 4))` here is the issue. You should pass parameters the order in which they are listed in function declaration. And do it without '='.

Comment: _"but it prints out NaN"_ - not sure how that would be the case - I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: prices.reduce is not a function" in both Chrome and Firefox. And if you add `console.log(prices, tip, tax)` to the start of your function, it should become clear why ...

Comment: @CBroe yeah you're right, I get the same error which I forgot to mention in the post. But I was using JSFiddle for this example, and it also printed out `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`calculateTotal(tip = 4)` doesn’t mean what you think it means.

It means:

1. Evaluate the expression `tip = 4` which:

   - Creates an implicit global `tip` (this is an error in strict mode, which you should be using)
   - Assigns the value `4` to that global
   - Evaluates as the value `4`
2. Assign the result of that expression as the first argument to the `calculateTotal` function

   - i.e. `calculateFunction(4)` where the second and third parameters are given their default values from the function definition.

JavaScript doesn’t have any feature that allows assignment to parameters by name, only position.

The usual way to handle that is by passing a single argument, an object, and using destructuring to turn it into variables.

```js
const example = ({ foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 3} = {}) => {
    console.log(foo, bar, baz);
};

example();
example({ bar: 17 });
```

Comment: Perhaps *"JavaScript doesn’t have any feature that allows **named** assignment to parameters."*? *(Emphasis just to show what I changed.)* (Since named parameters are often assigned. :-D )

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the position of your argument. Because you expect `prices` to be the first argument.

Solution is to use object as an paramater with default values.

```js
function calculateTotal({ prices = [], tip = 0, tax = 0 }) {
    return prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + tip + tax
}

console.log(calculateTotal({ tip:  4 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array::flat()` to simplify things:

```js
function calculateTotal(...args) {
    return args.flat().reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

console.log(calculateTotal(4));
console.log(calculateTotal(4, 4));
console.log(calculateTotal(4, [1,1,1], 5));
console.log(calculateTotal(4, 5, [1,1,1]));
console.log(calculateTotal([1,1,1], 4, 5));
```

As mentioned in other answers, you can pass an object with named properties.
One option is to use typed based arguments. It's used in jQuery for example, where arguments are processed based on their type. It's not liked by many I guess. The idea is that you don't care about order of your arguments, only of their types. Personally I like this because I just need to remember which types to pass as arguments without a need to remember order of arguments or their names.

```js
const parseArgs = args => {

  const out = {number: [], array: []};

  for(const arg of args){
    if(Array.isArray(arg)){
      out.array.push(arg);
    }else if(typeof arg === 'number'){
      out.number.push(arg);
    }
  }
  
  // do for strings, booleans, objects, etc
  
  return out;
};

function calculateTotal(...args) {
    
    args = parseArgs(args);

    const [tip = 0, tax = 0] = args.number;
    const [prices = []] = args.array;
   
    return prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + tip + tax
}

console.log(calculateTotal(4));
console.log(calculateTotal(4, 4));
console.log(calculateTotal(4, [1,1,1], 5));
console.log(calculateTotal(4, 5, [1,1,1]));
console.log(calculateTotal([1,1,1], 4, 5));
```